# chrome input field only see tops of characters in placeholder

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have been trying to create a web form that contains placeholder text.  If I view the form in IE, the text appear as it should.  However, if I view the same form in Chrome, it appears as though you are only seeing the top 2-3 pixels of each letter at the bottom of the text field.  I have been looking all over the web and haven't been able to find anyone with the same type of issue.
You can see the form at the following url:
https://dev5-web-fila.demandware.net/s/FILA/account

I'd appreciate any help I can get on this issue as I am at my wits end right now.

Chris Cote

Answer (score 1):

In your `style.css` there are some css declarations for [::-webkit-input-placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css).  You can either delete these or overwrite them.  E.g.

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder,
:-moz-placeholder,
::-moz-placeholder,
:-ms-input-placeholder {
   font-size: inherit;
}
```